# angular unit testing fakeasync vs whenstable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous

I'm writing unit tests for an angular component.  So far when testing async code from what I have read I have two approaches

- Approach 1: use `fakeAsync` along with `tick`
- Approach 2: use `async` along with `whenStable`

I preferred the first approach `fakeAsync`, however I noticed that this does no update ngModel when I modify an input element value.  However if I use `whenStable` with `async` then it works fine.  Is this expected ? I actually thought approach 1 and approach 2 were the same from what I have read so far.

Comment: for first approach you can run change detection with `fixture.detectChanges()`. Then, It might update the ngModel.

Comment: I actually tried this but it does not work, so I had to actually go into the component and set the individual field value manually.

Comment: @pandithpadaya can you provide some code?

Comment: actually its a fairly big component and difficult to provide a sample.